# Tree Comparison Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, comparison

I am looking for an algorithm to compare two trees.

I have this class in Java

```
public class TreeNodeDSP {

  TreeNodeDSP parent;
  List<TreeNodeDSP> children;
  NodeDSP value;

  public TreeNodeDSP(TreeNodeDSP parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    children = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public TreeNodeDSP(TreeNodeDSP parent, NodeDSP value) {
    this.parent = parent;
    children = new ArrayList<>();
    this.value = value;
  }

  public void addChild(TreeNodeDSP node) {
    if (node != null && node.getValue() != null) {
      if (children.stream().noneMatch(child -> Objects.equals(child.getValue(), node.getValue()))) {
        children.add(node);
      }
    }
  }

  public TreeNodeDSP getParent() {
    return parent;
  }

  public void cleanChildren() {
    children = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public int getChildrenCount() {
    return children.size();
  }

  public TreeNodeDSP getChildrenAt(int position) {
    if (children.size() > position && position > -1) {
      return children.get(position);
    }
    return null;
  }

  public List<TreeNodeDSP> getChildren() {
    return children;
  }

  public NodeDSP getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public boolean isLeaf() {
    return children.isEmpty();
  }

}
```

I think the code of `NodeDSP` class is not needed.

Now, I have an algorithm to populate my Tree (`TreeNodeDSP`) and facing problem performing operations based on Automatically populate Tree (calculating some conditions),

I populate manually my Tree and works.

I need to discover what is the difference in my Tree (manually Populated, and Automatically) in its nodes (internally), not only says are different Trees. When some node/leaf is different I need to print its contents.

But, I don't know how to begin with the comparison Algorithm.

Comment: You show code for tree class and then you are saying manually populate and automatically populate. What do you mean by that. Please make it clear in your question.

Comment: You mentioned about the class NodeDSP, but its code isn't here.